# How to find enhanced domains enabled in salesforce org via apex?

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument

I am looking for ways to find out whether salesforce org is enabled with enhanced domains or not via apex.

As per this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_formats.htm&type=5), the content (files) domain is different in each case. And dynamically finding out whether enhanced domains are enabled or not, will help to construct the absolute path of the salesforce file via apex.

I am trying to construct URL `<contentBaseURL>/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/Download`. We can use `URL.getOrgDomainUrl()` for `contentBaseURL` but salesforce internally does redirects to one of the following URLs based of enhanced domain enabled or not.

```
//with enhanced domain redirects to 
Content(files): MyDomainName.file.force.com

//without enhanced domain redirects to 
Content(files): MyDomainName--c.documentforce.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [DomainCreator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm) class for this. It will return the correct URL in both cases:

```
DomainCreator.getContentHostname()
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for, thanks.